# TcpListener not accepting client during http calls

Tags: tcplistener

I am running a test website using Node.js against localhost port 3000. I am able to see the website in my browser when its running but TCPListener doesn't see any requests.
My code looks something like this:

```
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3000);
listener.Start();
TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

While running in debug, the code stops and sits on listener.AcceptTcpClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally figured part of it out. I needed to use my internal IP address and also use it in my browser URL. Previously I tried localhost or my external IP address. I don't understand why neither of these options work or how you would connect the listener to those calls, but I was able to attach the listener to my internal IP address. @snus74 your comment about IPconfig made me think to use the internal IP address. Thanks!! –

Answer (score 1):

`listener.AcceptTcpClient()` is a blocking call which will wait for a client socket to connect. Your program being stuck on this instruction means your server is setup correctly.
This rather means no client is trying to connect to the server on this particular IP address

EDIT: try changing your server IP address from "127.0.0.1" (loopback) to the network IP address assigned to your machine, so that it can be visible to clients over the network (if your clients *are* expected to be on that network)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Since I have the web server listening to the same IP and port and able to connect to it using a web browser, shouldn't this server also be able to see that traffic?

Comment: what do you mean by "the same IP and port" ? which traffic ? traffic is generated by client instances with different Endpoints that try to connect to a server

Comment: If I understand your statement, you're referring to endpoints such as MVC endpoints which go through routing to direct the traffic to the correct URI. 
The calls are made to the same IP Address and port. The endpoints is the server application routing the traffic.

Comment: what I mean by endpoint is [IpAddress:port]. The clients that try to connect to your server should have a different endpoint than [serverIpAddress:serverPort], for instance [serverIpAddress:clientAPort] if you want it to run on the same machine

Comment: In that case, shouldn't it work it I set the IpAddress to IpAddress.Any? I tried this an still did not receive a connection.

Comment: I think the most reliable way is to set the Ip Address to your IPV4 network IP address. Not the loopback address (127.0.0.1), and set the port to Any, or 0

Comment: I have tried to set the IP address and port to any however I get the error, "The requested address is not valid in its context.". I am setting it using IPAddress.Parse("XX.XX.XX.XXX")

Comment: This wont work, try setting it as your network IPV4 address. (you get this this address by typing ipconfig in your Windows /Linux console

Comment: OK, I finally figured part of it out. I needed to use my internal IP address and also use it in my browser URL. Previously I tried localhost or my external IP address. I don't understand why neither of these options work or how you would connect the listener to those calls, but I was able to attach the listener to my internal IP address.
@snus74 your comment about IPconfig made me think to use the internal IP address. Thanks!!

Comment: glad it helped, I suspected the issue would be because of you using wrong IP addresses, thats why I suggested changing the IP address to the network  address assigned to your machine in my answer